# Optimization query (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, query-optimization

### I have this tables in MYSQL:

```
products(prodId, Hide)
cat_binds(prodId,SptPath)
params(paramId,prodId,langId,value)
```

### Query

```
SELECT 
        DISTINCT(params.value) 
FROM 
        products,
        cat_binds, 
        params 
WHERE 
        products.prodId = params.prodId 
        AND 
        params.paramId =  '1' 
        AND 
        params.langId =  '1' 
        AND 
        products.prodId = cat_binds.prodId 
        AND 
        cat_binds.SptPath LIKE '-2147483644\_%' 
        AND 
        products.Hide = '0'
```

How optimizing this query? How create right indexes which generate less rows wanted for result.

Thanks for help

Comment: everything referenced in the WHERE should be indexed.

Comment: it would be better if you can add the `explain` result.

Answer (score 0):

Use joins instead of cartisians which fetch undesired rows.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  (params.value)
FROM products
  LEFT JOIN cat_binds
    ON cat_binds.prodId = products.prodId
  LEFT JOIN params
    ON params.prodId = products.prodId
WHERE params.paramId = '1'
    AND params.langId = '1'
    AND cat_binds.SptPath LIKE '-2147483644\_%'
    AND products.Hide = '0'
```

Comment: JOINS generated similar result

Comment: @PavelSzabo your question is about optimization and you haven't asked for not getting the desired results. If your query is not fatching waht you want than post complete structure with sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL looks good and if you have added the Primary Index on all the IDs fields i think it will fine . MySQL will also optimized internally to make the order correct . I have only concern about the WHERE condition containing LIKE expression.  As you are using the '%' condition in the last I think adding Index to this column will be helpful but if you put '%' in front then index will have not much effect

Comment: You have right, if I get out LIKE expression, this query is fast and efficiently. Do you know, how change LIKE expression for better result?

Comment: read here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576778/mysql-optimization-like-vs . But remember expression like LIKE is costly affairs what ever you do . See if you have some alternate options available